# Moving text with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to move a line of text back and forth inside a colored background box. I can do this beautifully with the marquee tag, but as I heard its usage is not recommended so I decided to use CSS instead. Although I copied the form of the animation function from CSS tutorials but I can't figure out why the line doesn't move. Could you show me what's wrong with my code?

My HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Part 1</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" content="text/css" href="part1-2.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="background">
            <div class="title">I'm moving</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My CSS code:

```
div.background
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ffcc00;
}

div.title
{
    position: relative;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-animation: movingtitle 10s infinite alternate linear;
    animation: movingtitle 10s infinite alternate linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes movingtitle
{
    from {left: 0px;}
    to {left: 1366px;}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not implementing simple `@keyframes` function which gets invoked in some browsers and maybe yours also.
Also you can use `margin` in `animation`  functions as follows

```
@-webkit-keyframes movingtitle
{
    from {margin-left: 0px;}
    to {margin-left: 1366px;}
}
@keyframes movingtitle
{
    from {margin-left: 0px;}
    to {margin-left: 1366px;}
}
```

Hope it works!!!

Comment: Yeah, I just figured that out, too. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you tell me how to make the text push back after touching the border of the box? It keeps moving over the border.

Comment: @Brother Eye which box and border are you talking about as there is none in your code..

Comment: Oh, sorry, I mean the edge of the background. My text keeps moving over it before turning back. I want it to turn back right after touching the edge of the background.

Comment: @Brother Eye okay do one thing,use percentage instead of px in margin like    
    from {margin-left: 0%;}
    to {margin-left: 90%;} in both keyframes

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's a good way. I thought there must be some way to perform it precisely without adjusting the parameters manually.

Answer (score 2):

You may use text-indent:

```css
div.background
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ffcc00;
}

div.title
{
    position: relative;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-animation: movingtitle 10s infinite alternate linear;
    animation: movingtitle 10s infinite alternate linear;
  /* added */
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
}

@-webkit-keyframes movingtitle
{
/* modified */
    to {text-indent:100%;}
}
@keyframes movingtitle
{
/* modified */
    to {text-indent:100%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
            <div class="title">I'm moving</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Wow! Works like charm! Could you explain your solution for me? Why use text-indent and what is "white-space: nowrap" for?

Comment: @BrotherEye white-space:nowrap; keeps the text on on line (else it would wrap down the line reaching the right side. text-indent pushes or puls  the text according to the values set (usually used to show a new parapgraph with a classic average text-indent:1em;) 100% takes the full width of container.

Comment: I think I just figured out what's wrong. I forgot @keyframes after @-webkit-! Thank you very much! You just showed me a nice way to move!